Identify this 1980's (or earlier) TV Show/Movie shown in the 2015 Movie Pixels
The following screenshot is of a real TV or could be a movie that was shown in the sci-fi movie Pixels (2015):

In the movie it was depicted that in 1982 NASA released a shuttle with tapes of various TV shows and video games of the era, and that ended up in the hands of ET life forms which sent those back modified with different messages. 
I am pretty sure this is also probably a TV show in the 80's, as the film also displays other TV shows and personalities I know were real. 

It's Fantasy Island from the late 70s.

Fantasy Island is a unique resort in the Pacific Ocean, where there is very little that the mysterious overseer, Mr. Roarke, cannot provide. Thus, we have visitors have adventures that should be impossible, but this island can accommodate them such as visits to any time period they want or meet absolutely anyone they want see to do something they request. However, what actually happens is often far more than they expect as they face challenges that test their character in ways they never imagined.

Here are Mr Roarke and his sidekick Tattoo:

